# ¿Cuál es la manera más eficaz de escribir lineas de matrices ascendentes y descendientes?

Tags: python, matrices, matriz

Quiero imprimir una matriz que de como resultado lo siguiente(sin usar librerias):

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 
6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Lo he resuelto de dos maneras, pero siento que ambas son redundantes y creo que debe haber alguna manera más óptima de hacerlo, la cual estoy pasando por alto.

Esta es la primera:

```
for i in range(1,7):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        number = 1
    else:
        number = 6
    for j in range(1,7):
        if i % 2 != 0:
          print(number, end=' ')
          number += 1

        else:
            print(number, end=' ')
            number = number -1
    print(' ')
```

Esta es la segunda:

```
for i in range(1, 7):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        number = 6
        for j in range(1,7):
            print(number, end=' ')
            number -= 1
    else:
        number = 1
        for j in range(1,7):
            print(number, end=' ')
            number += 1

    print('')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si esto es más *eficiente* o no, pero seguramente es más pythónico:

```py
max = 6
fila = [x for x in range(1, max+1)]
matriz = [[*fila] if i % 2 == 0 else list(reversed(fila)) for i in range(0, max)]
```

Esto devuelve una matriz de `max` x `max` de la siguiente forma:

```py
[
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
  [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
]
```

**Corrección**
En vez de añadir la referencia a la variable `fila` dentro de la matriz, añadimos una copia de la misma usando el operador `*` que desempaca un iterable en sus elementos componentes (popularmente conocido como *operador splat*) y crea una copia "shallow" de la lista. Al ser sus elementos todos objetos primitivos la copia se puede considerar "deep" o completa.

Puedes consultar la documentación de [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) y un [ejemplo de uso](https://realpython.com/python-reverse-list/#creating-reversed-lists)
Espero que te ayude a resolver el problema

Comment: Es necesario avisar que habitualmente no vas a querer usar el nombre de una función built-in de python (como max) como variable. Pues cuando quieras, por ejemplo, usar la función builtin max, vas a obtener el valor puesto en dicha variable. Ejemplo `max = 1;max(max, 2)` te devolverá un error diciendo que los enteros no son llamables (o callables, en ingles), ya que max es 1.

Comment: Me di cuenta de un problema en tu respuesta... Cada vez que i % 2 == 0 es verdadero, estás agregando la lista fila, no una copia, si no la lista original, a la matriz. Esto derivará en el comportamiento inesperado de que modifiques la lista y se modifique en las demás filas de la matriz. Yo haría fila.copy().

Comment: Tienes razón, corregido. Gracias @DanteS.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
maxi = 6
for i in range(maxi):
    print(' '.join([str(x) for x in range(1, maxi+1)][::[1,-1][i % 2]]))
```

Explicación:

```
[str(x) for x in range(1, maxi+1)]
```

produce una lista de strings numéricos desde 1 hasta el valor máximo elegido:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Luego aplicamos `[::valor]` para copiar el string. Si `valor` es `1`, la copia es igual al original; si ponemos `-1`, entonces la copia se invierte.

Para determinar si hay que invertir o no, usamos módulo dos (`% 2`), con lo que el resultado alternara entre 0 y 1. Este valor lo usamos para indexar la lista `[-1,1]`, lo que finalmente nos da el *step* necesario para la copia.

**Resultado**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1

Process finished with exit code 0
```